# React + apolloClient error no renderiza informacion

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, apollo

estoy queriendo redirigir a un componente desde una ruta dinamica que toma como argumento el id del objeto a travez del url

```
localhost:5173/noticias/1234
```

supongamos que quiero dirigirme a la noticia con id 1234, el routing lo tengo bien hecho,
puedo acceder a cada noticia, al clickear el boton que me lleve al path con su respectivo id. dejo el codigo:

```
import { useNoticias } from '../pages/Noticias/custom-hooks'
export default function Details() {
   const datos = useNoticias()

}
```

del objeto datos recibo los siguientes valores `data.obtenerTodasLasNoticias.Noticia` y el contenido de cada una de las noticias(id,titulo,imagen,contenido) quiero desestructurar ese objeto `data.obtenerTodasLasNoticias.Noticia`, para obtener unicamente el contenido del objeto Noticia(id,titulo,imagen,contenido) porque necesito el id para luego `const noticia = noticias.find(noticia => noticia.id === id)` y poder renderizar el el contenido `noticia` en el

```
    return(
     <h1>{noticia.titulo}</h1>
            <img src={noticia.thumbnail} />
            <p>{noticia.contenido}</p>
)
```

como hago para desestructurar todo `data.obtenerTodasLasNoticias.Noticia` eso en una sola constante, o como hago para desestructurar ese objeto para obtener el id y hacer la comparacion porque el objeto llega bien
[image: objeto Noticia]

nose si me explique bien